# ubuntu 18.1: which filetypes (pdf, djvu, epub, mobi, azw3, chm) are depicted as thumbnails

Tags: filemanager, ebooks

Please check your file manager in a directory (where pdf, epub, djvu, doc, azw3 or any other ebook files are  located) and write me if they are depicted as thumbnails (+Ubuntu version).

thank you very much
Torsen

Comment: Why don't you try a live USB?

Comment: Please would you describe the advantages to use a live usb?

Comment: You'll get to know what a distro can or can't do regarding what you've listed in your question: https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#0